# Fixed column and fixed header and scrolling text using css?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to make a fixed column and fixed header on a table with the rest as scrolling text by using CSS.

But not using jQuery, just simple CSS and JavaScript

just like xls
Thanks

Comment: you might get more answers on http://doctype.com

Comment: A related doctype post: http://doctype.com/whats-current-state-art-layout-fixed-header-footer

Comment: answers should be posted here also and not be referenced, for the sake of proper QA mechanism. the link might die, but answers here stays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there you go::

this in styleSheet::

```
.box{
position:fixed;
}

    .bb { 
    position:absolute; 
    left:0px; 
    background-color:#AEC5EF; 
    width:200px; 
    height:200px; 
    } 

    .tt { 
  position:fixed; 
    left:200px; 
    background-color:#D4DDEF; 
    width:300px; 
    height:200px; 
    }
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="box"> 
        <td class="bb">  </td>
        <td class="tt">main text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

take it or leave it ....^_^